# Continuity of series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I have following problem:
Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ is continuous for $x>1$. I know that I need to show the given series is uniformly convergent for $x>1$ but I don't understand how to do so.

Comment: It is dominated by $\sum \frac  1 {r^{n}}$ on $[r,\infty)$ for any $r>1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is not uniformly convergent on $(1,+\infty)$  because if we fix $N \in \Bbb{N}$ then

$$\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}f_k \geq \sum_{k=N}^Mf_k,\forall M>N$$

thus $\sup_{x>1}\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}f_k \geq \lim_{x \to 1^+}\sum_{k=N}^{M}f_k=\frac{M-N}{2},\forall M>N$

Thus $\sup_{x>1}\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}f_k=+\infty, \forall N \in \Bbb{N}$

But the series is continuous for $x>1$

Because the convergence is uniform on every interval of the form $[c,+\infty)$ when $c>1$

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answers and comments. It seems that for continuity I just need uniform convergence on $[r, \infty)$, for any $r>1$ rather than on $(1, \infty)$. Can you please State the theorem which guarantees so?

Comment: @UserA its not a specific theorem...just take a point $y>1$ then you can find a point $1<z<y$...now the series convergence uniformly on $[c,+\infty)$ and and because of the uniform convergence of continuos function the limit is continuous at this interval and hence at $y$